# View models vs dependency injection

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, dependency-injection

In a large, multi-user application I have the following set-up:

- A `Context` class containing a reference to the root of my data model. From here, I can reach all other models.
- A `Commander` class that has methods for manipulating the data model. For example, for an object `Layout` there is a method `Commander.ResizeLayout(layout, width, height)`. Note that underlying this class is a client-server architecture; the server is contacted before updating the `Layout.width` and `Layout.height` properties locally.
- Internally, the `Commander` has a reference to the `Context` and makes sure that after processing a command, the corresponding objects are updated.
- Now, I'm working on a view model (say `LayoutViewModel`) that is used for a User Control (`LayoutForm`) for editing the width and height of a `Layout`.

My goal is to have the  view (model) utilize the `Commander` class to process any changes made in the view. Right now, I'm passing the `Context` and `Commander` to the main window constructor. Within the XAML files, the `Commander` object together with relevant data objects (e.g. the selected `Layout`) are passed to smaller controls like the `LayoutForm`.

Here's my struggle: It doesn't feel right to keep passing around objects like a `Commander` via bindings. At the same time, I also believe using global variables (e.g. `App.Commander`) is not the way to go and dependency injection from `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection` (which I use in various other projects in my solution) seems not globally accessible in WPF.

What would be the right way to access an object like the `Commander` from a low-level control? Or am I missing a bigger point here?

Thanks a lot for any suggestion that helps me move forward!

Comment: there should not be references to Commander in MainWindow, or other windows or controls. Views should use only ViewModels (and ideally only via bindings). If some data/action is required from Commander, then ViewModel should organize that, not View

Comment: Hi @ASh, that would be even better! However, my problem is: The view model needs to get a reference to the Commander but is typically instantiated by the View (either as resource in XAML or in the code behind)... So how does the ViewModel get this reference?

Comment: You could inject the view model with any reference it needs.

Comment: @mm8 In your approach, where would the view model be instantiated (XAML or code behind) and how would you pass the references? Downside of code behind is that I'd lose the typehinting capabilities in XAML, downside of XAML is that I'd keep passing around references right?

Comment: In the code-behind or wherever you are instantiate them currently (apart from XAML).